# Addition and multiplication of connected spaces

Tags: manifolds, vector-fields

I am an engineer so I apologize for my math language, if it is not the most suitable.

How can I define addition and multiplication between two connected differentiable manifolds $m_1$ and $m_2$, i.e. a connected space (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) that is also a differentiable manifold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).

My goal is to find a kind of "interpolation" of a vector field $v_1$ defined on $m_1$ and vector field $v_2$ defined on $m_2$. The two vector fields are actually governed by the same equation, but the manifold changes. I also do not want to solve (because it is time consuming on a PC) again the new vector field on the new manifold.

Or alternatively, given $m_1$ and $v_1$ if I perturb $m_1$ into $m_2$ by a "small" parameter, how will the vector field change?

If there isn't a simple/direct answer can you point me to some literature?

Comment: I am afraid your question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: I know, I'll try to make it clearer. In the 1D case, the domain of a function is an interval. With the help of interval arithmetic, we can define addition and multiplication of intervals. At first, what I need is an analog for the n-dimensional manifold case.

Comment: I do not know what you mean even in 1d case: What wold you want a "sum" of two circles to be? The Minkowski sum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition You really have to work out one (or two) simple example in detail so that *you* know what you are asking about.

Comment: In the 2D simply-connected case, assume the first shape $S_1$ to be defined by a closed curved-with the parametrization $x_1$ from [0,1] to R-and its inner region, and the second shape accordingly. Given two corresponding points on the boundary of the two curves, add them (vector sum of the vectors from the coordinate origin to the points) to get a point on the new boundary. Starting from these points and running from 0 to 1, compute the sum of each point on the two boundaries, in order to find the boundary of the new shape.

Comment: If you have the map between the two manifolds then the map differential maps tangent vectors.